# Android MediaPlayer play m3u8 only audio streamming not worked

Tags: android, audio, media-player, m3u8

Hi every one i write a code to play fm radio waves. In my code there are a progressbar and two buttons one of them for play and another for stop. when i click play button it not happen. how can i solve this problem? or is there good suggest for me to play audio m3u8 files?
The code I'm using is:

```
    public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private ProgressBar playSeekBar;

    private Button buttonPlay;

    private Button buttonStopPlay;

    private MediaPlayer player;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        initializeUIElements();

        initializeMediaPlayer();

    }

    private void initializeUIElements() {

        playSeekBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        playSeekBar.setMax(100);
        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

        buttonStopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopPlay);
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
        buttonStopPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonPlay) {
            startPlaying();
        } else if (v == buttonStopPlay) {
            stopPlaying();
        }
    }

    private void startPlaying() {
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
        buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);

        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        player.prepareAsync();

        player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                player.start();
            }
        });

    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
            initializeMediaPlayer();
        }

        buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        try {

            player.setDataSource("http://url.m3u8");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
                Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem by [vitamio](https://www.vitamio.org/en/) library. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to call setOnPreparedListener() before prepareAsync() if you don't get onPrepared() callback.

Comment: tanks for request, actually when i changed .m3u8 url to .mp3 url it is work correctly. but for .m3u8 it isn't play any thing

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#network), Android 4.0 and above doesn't support mp3 chunks. It supports only ts-files.

Furthermore, if your link hasn't *.m3u8* in the end a MediaPlayer can't play it. Which tells that `Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl` is abandoned. And you must have *.m3u8* extension in the link.